# Database array only returns one row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am sorry for my lazy title. I hope that a moderator could improve it so the database won't get infected.

I got the following code (**forum.php**);

```
<?php

$res = $db->query('
  SELECT *
  FROM forums_categories
  ORDER BY category_id
');

while ($row = $db->fetch_array($res)) {
  $categories = array(
    'ID'   => $row['category_id'],
    'NAME' => $row['category_name']
  );

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($categories);
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

And I got the following database structure;

```
|---------------|-------------------|
|  category_id  |  category_name    |
|---------------|-------------------|
|  1            | Example 1         |
|  2            | Example 2         |
|  3            | Example 3         |
|  4            | Example 4         |
|  5            | Example 5         |
|  6            | Example 6         |
|---------------|-------------------|
```

But my array only returns 1 value:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 1
    [NAME] => Example 1
)
```

Oh and if somebody likes to know how my `$db->fetch_array` looks like:

```
<?php

function fetch_array($result)
{
return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

How can I return all rows in my array? Thank you for reading and thank you for replying!

Comment: Just a reminder: Try not to use `SELECT *` - Reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting the previous value of `$categories` on each iteration

```
$categories[] = array(
    'ID'   => $row['category_id'],
    'NAME' => $row['category_name']
  );
```

You might also want to initialize an empty array

```
$categories = array();
```

before your loop to avoid warnings.

Comment: We're declaring variables not only to prevent warnings, because warning is not problem. It's only telling us that we have problem.

Comment: Thank you for your information. It still does return one row but I get the feeling I am close.